# combining elements of 2 list in a certain way

Tags: python, list, iteration, python-zip

i have a doubt in combining 2 lists into one in a certain way.
can anyone help me out?

i have 2 lists

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

i want the resultant list like `['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd1', 'e2']`
The result list must be generated by iterating through the list a and simultaniously cycling through the list b.

i have tried the following code

`r = ['%s%d' % item for item in zip(a,b)]`

but the output I'm getting is,

`['a1', 'b2', 'c3']`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to repeat the shortest list:

```
from itertools import cycle

out = [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in zip(a, cycle(b))]
```

If you don't know which of a/b is longest:

```
from itertools import cycle

out = [f'{x}{y}' for x, y in
       (zip(a, cycle(b)) if len(a)>len(b) else zip(cycle(a), b))]
```

Output: `['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd1', 'e2']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to iterate through the two lists simultaneously

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
b = [1, 2, 3]

result = [x+str(y) for x, y in zip(a, b*len(a))]
print(result)
```